# Basic Struts1.2 Application which forwards to JSP page

Tags: java, struts-1

I am Having a Struts 1.2 Application with following web.xml and struts-config.xml

**web.xml**

```
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>action</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>config</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/struts-config.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>action</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

**struts-config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE struts-config PUBLIC
                  "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 1.2//EN"
                  "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-config_1_2.dtd">
    <struts-config>
    <form-beans>
            <form-bean name="Welcome"
                type="com.mugil.tutor.action.Sample" />
        </form-beans>
    <action-mappings>
        <action path="/Welcome" name="Welcome"  type="com.mugil.tutor.action.Sample">
            <forward name="success" path="/welcome.jsp"/>
        </action>
    </action-mappings>
    </struts-config>
```

The directory structure of the Files is as shown below

[image]

I want to display  welcome message in welcome.jsp.This should happen after I receive success message from Sample.java

**Sample.java**

```
package com.mugil.tutor.action;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.apache.struts.action.Action;
import org.apache.struts.action.ActionForm;
import org.apache.struts.action.ActionForward;
import org.apache.struts.action.ActionMapping;

public class Sample extends Action
{
     public ActionForward execute(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form,
                HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
                throws Exception 
    {
         String target = "success"; 
         return mapping.findForward(target);
    }
}
```

**welcome.jsp**

```
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Welcome to Struts 1.2</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

I dont know where I am going wrong.Its showing different error messages when I tried to fix one.

Comment: HTTP Status 404 - Invalid path /welcome.jsp was requested

Comment: Where have you kept the JSP file ?

Comment: Have I coded the right way to do this. Forwarding to JSP page based on message from Sample.java

Comment: In web folder u can c the directory structure in above pic

Comment: What will happen if you just try to access `welcome.jsp` directly from browser, typing it in URL?

Answer (score 1):

I assume this is because you have mapped the `ActionServlet` to the url pattern `/*`. I don't think Struts 1 handles "extensionless" urls, and it would interfere with the path to `/welcome.jsp`. Try changing the url pattern to `*.do` or some other suffix.